# How to use bcrypt in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: hash, codeigniter-3, bcrypt, password-hash

To go straight to the point I just started using Codeigniter 3 and I am building a login system but I don't know how to implement a BCRYPT hashing algorithm for the password.

Here's the

**controllers > Login.php:**

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


        function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->model('dashboard_model');
  
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        #Redirect to Admin dashboard after authentication
        if ($this->session->userdata('user_login_access') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'dashboard');
            $data=array();
            #$data['settingsvalue'] = $this->dashboard_model->GetSettingsValue();
            $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function Login_Auth(){   
    $response = array();

    /**   $this->input->post 
    **used to retrieve the value of a form input field named "email" that was submitted via the HTTP POST method.
    */
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember');
    // Login input validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'User Email', 'trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[7]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[6]');
    
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback','UserEmail or Password is Invalid');
        redirect(base_url() . 'login', 'refresh');      
    }
    else{
        //Validating login
        $login_status = $this->validate_login($email, $password);
        $response['login_status'] = $login_status;
        if ($login_status == 'success') {
            if($remember){
                setcookie('email',$email,time() + (86400 * 30));
                setcookie('password',$this->input->post('password'),time() + (86400 * 30));
                redirect(base_url() . 'login', 'refresh');
                
            } else {
                if(isset($_COOKIE['email']))
                {
                    setcookie('email',' ');
                }
                if(isset($_COOKIE['password']))
                {
                    setcookie('password',' ');
                }               
                redirect(base_url() . 'login', 'refresh');
            }
        
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback','UserEmail or Password is Invalid');
            redirect(base_url() . 'login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
    }
    //Validating login from request
    function validate_login($email = '', $password = '') {
        $credential = array('em_email' => $email, 'em_password' => $password,'status' => 'ACTIVE');


        $query = $this->login_model->getUserForLogin($credential);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_login_access', '1');
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_login_id', $row->em_id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $row->first_name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('email', $row->em_email);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_image', $row->em_image);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_type', $row->em_role);
            return 'success';
        }
    }
}
```

**models > Login_model.php**

```php
<?php

    class Login_model extends CI_Model{


    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    
    }
    public function getUserForLogin($credential){           
    return $this->db->get_where('employee', $credential);
    }
    public function getdata(){
    $query =$this->db->get('users');
    $result=$query->result();
    return $result;
    }
    //*check if employee email is existing**//
    public function Does_email_exists($email) {
        $user = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
        $sql = "SELECT `email` FROM $user
        WHERE `email`='$email'";
        $result=$this->db->query($sql);
        if ($result->row()) {
            return $result->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function insertUser($data){
        $this->db->insert('users',$data);
    }
    public function UpdateKey($data,$email){
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->update('users',$data);
    }
    public function UpdatePassword($key,$data){
        $this->db->where('forgotten_code',$key);
        $this->db->update('users',$data);       
    }   
    public function UpdateStatus($verifycode,$data){
        $this->db->where('confirm_code',$verifycode);
        $this->db->update('users',$data);       
    }
    //check if employee email is existing//
    public function Does_Key_exists($reset_key) {
        $user = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
        $sql = "SELECT `forgotten_code` FROM $user
        WHERE `forgotten_code`='$reset_key'";
        $result=$this->db->query($sql);
        if ($result->row()) {
            return $result->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function GetUserInfo($key){
        $user = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
        $sql = "SELECT `password` FROM $user
        WHERE `forgotten_code`='$key'";
        $query=$this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $query->row();
        return $result;         
    }       
    public function GetuserInfoBycode($verifycode){
        $user = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $user
        WHERE `confirm_code`='$verifycode'";
        $query=$this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $query->row();
        return $result;         
    }   
}
?>
```

I don't know how to implement a bcrypt hashing password in codeigniter 3. If anyone knows how to please tell me the steps I should take?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement a BCRYPT algorithm, it is already there:

to Creates a password hash

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

to verifies that a password matches a hash

```
password_verify(string $password, string $hash);
```

note: password_verify return bool

to read more:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 0):

In your *CodeIgniter* project, you'll need to implement custom password hashing using the chosen encryption scheme (*Bcrypt*). CodeIgniter does not have Bcrypt as its default hashing algorithm, so you'll need to create custom functions to handle password hashing and verification.

**you can implement custom Bcrypt hashing in CodeIgniter:**

```
// application/helpers/custom_hash_helper.php

if (!function_exists('custom_bcrypt_hash')) {
   function custom_bcrypt_hash($value) {
     return password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_bcrypt_verify')) {
  function custom_bcrypt_verify($value, $hashedValue) {
     return password_verify($value, $hashedValue);
  }
}
```

Load the custom helper in your CodeIgniter application where you need to use it. You can do this in your controller or autoload the helper in the `autoload.php` configuration file.

Now you can use the `custom_bcrypt_hash()` function to hash passwords before storing them and the `custom_bcrypt_verify()` function to verify passwords during login in your CodeIgniter application. These functions will be compatible with Laravel's **Bcrypt hashes.**